# How to force PC automatically shut down upon overheating

Tags: laptop, software-rec, shutdown

I have a [Sony Vaio VPC-CW21FX](http://www.sonystyle.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10151&catalogId=10551&langId=-1&productId=8198552921666033768#additionalImage1%22) at home, and I leave it open most of the time. Since I'm a little bit paranoid, I have the possibility of overheating on my mind when I'm not at home.

So, I'm looking for a preferably free software to force my laptop shut down when the temperature values exceed the reliable threshold. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any third party software.

I have not encountered a single machine in the last five years that does not have some sort of protection built in to the motherboard that shuts down before certain areas reach a critical temperature.

Comment: Does a mobo shutdown in this sort of case just effectively cut power? Presumably it won't ask the OS to shutdown nicely? Althought, I suppose that might be less of a concern than burning components.

Comment: @DMA57361 - Correct, it just cuts power. unless you have terrible ventilation, it is hard to get to critical temperature. On top of this, in the BIOS, you should be able to configure warnings (beeps) before critical temperatures.

Comment: fair enough. It's been at least a decade since I had real temp troubles with a machine - back then I used monitoring software to trigger `shutdown` and it *almost* worked reliably.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows (you don't say what OS), you should be able to use [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com) to perform a graceful shutdown when a threshold is reached.